# Styled-Components Pass Props For Condition

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to make a conditional icon with `styled-components`. But I need to pass props like function params. Because I need to change the icon with the condition.

```
export const RadioCheck = ({checked}) => styled(checked ? FaCheckCircle : FaRegCircle)`
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0 2em;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: ${props => props.checked ? primary : `transparent`}
`
```

Is there any way for this or I need to create two different components and use them?

Comment: Is that what you're looking for: https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props ?

Comment: That part ok. I want to pass props for component condition. 
styled(checked ? FaCheckCircle : FaRegCircle)` like this. Actually it needs to return different component.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you should use the condition where you return the icon to decide which component to use.

Something like

```
return(
  <div>
  {checked ? 
  <FaCheckCircle
    //... your props
  /> 
  : 
  <FaRegCircle
    //... props
  />
}
</div>
)
```

If it's helpful to you, it is possible to style a styled component, such as

```
const FirstComponent = styled.div`
  //some styling
`

const SecondComponent = styled(FirstComponent)`
  //some more styling
`
```

Comment: This solution absolutely works. But maybe is there another way for it much cleaner.